# libphp5.so file not reflecting changes made in php.ini

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php5, centos6

I have been trying to update the **upload_max_filesize** of my **php.ini** file to **200M**.  I have got it to successfully save however it is not reflecting the changes on my server (it still lists the **upload_max_filesize** as **2M**.  I did do a httpd service restart, and I created a phpinfo file which says that it is in fact loading the **/etc/php.ini** configuration file.

One thing I have noticed is that the **libphp5.so** file is not reflecting this change.  I have done service restarts, and force reloads, and have not been able to successfully get the size to change.

Any help on why this is not changing would be greatly appreciated.

**edit**: Here's an image of some of the settings for reference:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0N4H.png

Comment: What about clearing your browser cache? Or try with another browser.

Comment: Can you please tell me the output of this command: `cat /etc/php.ini | egrep 'upload_max_filesize|post_max_size'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP back. I figured out the issue. I ran `php -c /etc/php/php.ini -i | grep upload_max_filesize` and discovered a small typo elsewhere in the php.ini file. (I attempted to edit the timeout value, and had left in a parenthesis). After taking out the parenthesis, and restarting the service, the upload value was correctly adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebooting the entire server, just to ensure that **everything** has been restarted?

Have you also looked in the apache config to see if it has been overruled by any options in there?

Comment: I just completely restarted the server, and unfortuantely that does not seem to have resolved the issue.  I also searched through the config file and did not see anything that seems to predefine it.